# Angular $compile scope Error with Jquery prepend

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm moving from Jquery to Angular. Therefor I still mix jquery code with angular. In this case I want to add some html in a div. And also want all the magic of Angular. It is showing this error

```
ReferenceError: scope is not defined
at Scope.$scope.addTooth
```

Here the code

index.html

```
<div class="q">
        <span ng-repeat="i in teethSetUL" ng-click="addTooth(i.type,i.location+i.id)">
            {{i.id}}
        </span>
</div>
```

app.js

```
$scope.addTooth = function(type,id){
    if($scope.selectedTeeth.indexOf(id) == -1){

        // item is not in the array
        $scope.selectedTeeth.push(id);

        console.log($scope.selectedTeeth);
        $('.tooth-info-body').prepend($compile('<div class="col-xs-12 tooth" id="ts-'+id+'"><img src="img/tooth.png" class=" col-xs-2 img-responsive"><div class="col-xs-8"><span><b> '+ type + ' <small> ('+id+')</small></b></span><select class="form-control"><option value="metal">Metal</option><option value="ring">Ring</option><option value="rest">Rest</option><option value="ni-cr">Ni-Cr</option><option value="zirconia">Zirconia</option><option value="ceramic">Ceramic</option><option value="other">other</option></select></div><div class="col-xs-2 text-right" style="padding-top: 25px;"><a ng-click="removeTooth('+id+')" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a></div></div>')(scope));
        scope.apply();
    }else{
        alert("you cannot select this again");
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you forget jquery. Your example doesn't require it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed  **$** symbol in your scope and apply().

**Solution 1 :**

Please try  this below code

`$scope.$apply();` instead of `scope.apply()`

**Solution 2 :**

Remove the `scope.apply()` for avoiding some bad codes

**Suggestion :**

Please verify to assign `$scope` in your controller parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$scope.$apply();
```

instead of

```
scope.apply();
```

Comment: This should be `$scope.$apply();` does not `$scope.apply();`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing it using anti pattern of AngularJS, you could simply do it by using `ng-repeat`, just add newly added in one array.

**Markup**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 tooth" id="ts-{{obj.id}}" ng-repeat="obj in objects">
    <img src="img/tooth.png" class=" col-xs-2 img-responsive">
    <div class="col-xs-8"><span><b> {{obj.type}}<small> ({{obj.id}})</small></b></span>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option value="metal">Metal</option>
            <option value="ring">Ring</option>
            <option value="rest">Rest</option>
            <option value="ni-cr">Ni-Cr</option>
            <option value="zirconia">Zirconia</option>
            <option value="ceramic">Ceramic</option>
            <option value="other">other</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 text-right" style="padding-top: 25px;"><a ng-click="removeTooth(id)" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a></div>
</div>
```

**Where you were wrong?**

It should be

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()
```

> But NOTE it is considered as bad pattern. Don't use this.